# Knowing the network utilization by an ANDROID APPLICATION

Tags: android

Is there a way to know how my Android application utilizes the network in real time, which in turn will help me to analyse the battery consumption when connected to a particular network. Also is it possible to optimize my android application to reduce the battery consumption.

Comment: see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939939/android-how-can-i-find-the-data-usage-on-per-application-basis

Comment: see my answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20184510/calculating-mobile-and-wifi-data-usage-of-each-application-in-android/20184623#20184623