# How to calculate remaining internet data balance in android?

Tags: android, android-data-usage

For an instance, 2 days before, I've purchased **500 MB** of data plan, say 
30-3-2016. Which means i'm using that data plan till now. Here whats my requirement is, I want to show the remaining data balance of that purchased plan. How to achieve this?

I've searched for this in google and i got some clues like, need to use **TrafficStats**

If it is that be the only solution then,

Can any one tell me how to calculate the remaining internet data balance using that **TrafficStats** ?

Comment: refer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20184510/calculating-mobile-and-wifi-data-usage-of-each-application-in-android or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939939/android-how-can-i-find-the-data-usage-on-a-per-application-basis or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7638292/trafficstats-api-android-and-calculation-of-daily-data-usage

Comment: check app on play store [smartbro](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smartbro)

Comment: @saurabh gupta Do you know how to check data balance using ussd ? I meant programatically